# Finding minimum in a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, searching, mathematical-optimization

Imagine I have the following list

```
{{0, {2,3}}, {-1, {5,3}}, {2, {2,6}}, {5, {5,0}}, {0, {1,1}}, {-2, {10,2}}, {3, {4,2}}};
```

I want to pick the element in the list which has the minimal first entry. That is, I would like to minimize with respect to the first element of each pair `{a, {b,c}}`. In our case, I would get the element `{-2, {10,2}}`, since `-2` is the minimum of the first element list `{0,-1,2,5,0,-2,3}`.

Any efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `MinimalBy[yourList, First]` will return a list containing that one element. If you just want the one element, use `First @ MinimalBy[...]`.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible to get all the minima?

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
 {{0, {2, 3}}, {-1, {5, 3}}, {2, {2, 6}}, {5, {5, 0}}, 
  {0, {1, 1}}, {-2, {10, 2}}, {3, {4, 2}}};
```

Using `TakeSmallestBy`

```
TakeSmallestBy[First, 1] @ list
```

{{-2, {10, 2}}}

Get the two smallest sublists (by first entry) and their positions

```
TakeSmallestBy[list -> {"Element", "Index"}, First, 2]
```

{{{-2, {10, 2}}, 6}, {{-1, {5, 3}}, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy` and `Min`:

```
#[Min@#] &@GroupBy[list, First]

(*{{-2, {10, 2}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alist = {{0, {2, 3}}, {-1, {5, 3}}, {2, {2, 6}}, {5, {5, 0}}, {0, {1, 
     1}}, {-2, {10, 2}}, {3, {4, 2}}};

First@SortBy[alist, First]
alist[[First@OrderingBy[alist, First]]]
GroupBy[alist, First] // KeySort // First // First
Extract[alist, First@Position[alist[[All, 1]], Min@alist[[All, 1]]]]
```

After v13.2:

```
Extract[alist, PositionSmallest[alist[[All,1]],1]]
```

---

> {{-2, {10, 2}}}